# add to cart function is not working like add to cart function does not get any data about product

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

i write a add product function but code for add product function is not working.i am working on ecomerece website here is the code for product category page when i click the add to cart button then handle add product function is not working function is written in app.js file i share the code of the function with this code

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Front/Header/Header';
import Nav from './Nav/Nav';
import './css/products_b.css';

 const Bed_Sheets=(props) =>{
    //  console
    
     const data  = props.productitems;
     
 const {handleAddProduct}=props;
     return(
         <> 
      <Header/> 
            <div className='products1'>
                {data.map((productitem) =>(
                    console.log(productitem.price), 
             <div className='card1'>
               <div>
                   <img className='products1-image' 
                    src={productitem.image}
                    alt={productitem.price}/>
                
                    </div>

                    <div>

                   <h3 className='products1-name'>{productitem.Name}

                   </h3>
                   </div>
                    <div>
                    <h3 className='products1-price'>${productitem.price}


                   </h3>
                   </div>
                  
                  <button className='products1-add-button' 
                  onClick={() => handleAddProduct(productitem)}> Add To Cart</button>
                  {/* <div>
                  <button className='products1_view'> view product</button>
                  
                  </div>*/}
                  
               </div>
               
                    
               
               ))}  
          </div>
         </>
     );
     
 };
 export default Bed_Sheets;
```

here is the code for handle add product function that is written on app.js component

```
const { productitems } = data;
  const [cartitems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  // const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  // const History = useHistory();

  const handleAddProduct = (product) => {
  //  console.log(product);
     const ProductExist = cartitems.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
    //  console.log(ProductExist);
    //  setCartItems(ProductExist);

    if (ProductExist) {
      setCartItems(
      
         cartitems.map((item )=> item.id === product.id ? 
        {...ProductExist ,quantity:ProductExist.quantity +1}:item)
      )
    }
    else {
      setCartItems([...cartitems,{...product,quantity:1}])
    }
  }
  const handleRemoveProduct = (product) => {
    const ProductExist = cartitems && cartitems.find((item) => item.id === product.id);
    if (ProductExist.quantity === 1) {
      setCartItems(
        cartitems.filter((item) => item.id !== product.id)
        );
    }
    else {
      setCartItems(
       cartitems && cartitems.map((item) => item.id === product.id ?
          { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity - 1 }
          : item)
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple example. Click on some products to add them to your cart. Check the updated cart quantity in the output

```js
function App({ products = [] }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState({})
  function addToCart(product) {
    return event => setCart({
      ...cart,
      [product.id]: {
        ...product,
        quantity: cart[product.id] == null
          ? 1
          : cart[product.id].quantity + 1
      }
    })
  }
  return <div>
    {products.map(p =>
      <button type="button" onClick={addToCart(p)} children={p.name} />
    )}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(cart, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

const products = [
  { id: 1, name: "ginger" },
  { id: 2, name: "garlic" },
  { id: 3, name: "turmeric" }
]

ReactDOM.render(<App products={products}/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can use a similar technique to remove an item from the cart

```js
function App({ products = [] }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState({
    1: { id: 1, name: "ginger", quantity: 5 },
    2: { id: 2, name: "garlic", quantity: 6 },
    3: { id: 3, name: "tumeric", quantity: 7 },
  })
  function removeFromCart(product) {
    return event => {
      setCart(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(cart).filter(c => c[0] != product.id)))
    }
  }
  return <div>
    {Object.values(cart).map(p =>
      <div>
        {p.name} ({p.quantity})
        <button type="button" onClick={removeFromCart(p)} children="❌" />
      </div>
    )}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(cart, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

const products = [
  { id: 1, name: "ginger" },
  { id: 2, name: "garlic" },
  { id: 3, name: "turmeric" }
]

ReactDOM.render(<App products={products}/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```